# Trying to get intended url in LoginController in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to capture the intended url in my LoginController so I can execute some logic in a `showLoginForm()` method I added to the controller so I can send the user to a specific view based on the intended URL.

I've tried the following and I cannot get it to work:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
  $intededUrl Session::put('url.intended', URL::full());

  // my base application url is http://www.websites.com:8080

  if (starts_with($intededUrl, url('/admin'))) // i want all routes that begin with http://www.websites.com:8080/admin to go here
    return view('auth.login');

  return view('themes.'.env('APP_THEME', 'mango').'.auth.login'); // but it keeps taking me here
}
```

I'm using Laravels `starts_with()` method to try and match the start of the url string.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. I needed `Session::get('url.intended');`